# Unable to start ElasticSearch Pod

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

A few months back, I deployed the Elastic-Search (version - 8.0.1) on Kubernetes (GCP) as a service as External load balancer using this [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html).

Now, I am unable to perform any read or write operation on ElasticSearch. I checked the logs, in which I found that memory of the node is almost full.

**Here are some logs which support this analysis:**

> flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [hulk-es-default-0][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data] free: 18.5mb[1.8%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
>
> Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [RED] (reason: [shards failed [[1][0]]]).
>
> This node is unhealthy: health check failed on [/usr/share/elasticsearch/data].`

**Here are the errors that are coming when performing any read/write operation:**

> elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(503, 'master_not_discovered_exception', None)
>
> elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=****): Read timed out. (read timeout=30))

I increased the capacity of my elasticsearch persistent volume claim(PVC) but was unable to create the pod with that new volume.

I followed the following steps -

- Set the allowVolumeExpansion field to true in their StorageClass object(s)
- Scaled ElasticSearch Operator Deployment to 0 Replicas.
- Deleted the statefulset Object without deleting the pods using

  `kubectl delete sts <statefulset-name> --cascade=orphan`

Before deleting I saved the yaml of the statefulset using

```
kubectl get sts <statefulset-name> -o yaml
```

- Increased the storage in capacity in the yaml file of PVC.
- Recreated the StatefulSet with the new storage request by the yaml file I saved using

`kubectl apply -f file-name.yml`

- Scaled back the operator deployment to 1

But, when I recreated the stateful set,  the `CrashLoopBackOff` error is being shown every-time.

Following are some logs -

- readiness probe failed
- Likely root cause: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
- using data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sdb)]], net usable_space [0b], net total_space [975.8mb], types [ext4]

The persistent disk's volume that the ES pod is accessing is increased but still the pod is unable to start.
Can anyone guide me here, what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be an issue with the disk space ( /usr/share/elasticsearch/data).
Verify that the persistent volume with the required size is available and is bound to the elasticsearch pod through PVC object.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, for some reason the Pod is not seeing the new volume Size. Have you tried [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-expansion), for the GKE Volume expansion?

If the Pod is always in the `CrashLoopBackOff` state you can use e.g: `kubectl debug mypod -it --image=busybox` So you will attach a debug container to your Pod and check what is going on with the mounted volume.

Others things you can also do is to create a snapshot/backup of your Volume and restore it on a new bigger volume to see if the Issue still persist.